# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all

Tags: python, pandas

[Data of Csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9RPD.png)

```
 import pandas as pd
    import csv
    df = pd.read_csv('niftsuper50.csv')
    close = df.Close
    supertrend = df.st

    if (close > supertrend):
        print (close)
```

I need the Value of Close column where its being true

Comment: Please provide example of your data.

Your answer lies here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Comment: data image kept

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but you did not supply your full code, so it is hard to know if it is what you wanted.
    df = df[df['Close']>supertrend]

Answer (score 0):

Close seems to be a keyword .. so try to use df["close"] and try compare